# Boot freeze after install fresh of 16.04 and nvidia drivers

Tags: boot, nvidia, 16.04

I've been struggling with a fresh 16.04 desktop install on PC with Nvidia GTX 950. Initial install is fine. Only thing is in Nouveau my 4k monitor only goes up to full hd resolution. After I install proprietary driver from Nvidia (I've tried 361 through screen and 364 trhough ppa) and reboot PC it freezes right after Grub. With 361 on black screen with blinking cursor , with 364 on either black or purple screen without cursor. Either way it's not booting. With 361 I did get to boot a couple of intermittent times and it dit show 4k resolution but it only booted like one in 20 attempts.

I've tried everything I could find like nomodeset, different clock settings, bios settings, more than 10 fresh reinstalls with different options etc but cannot find a working model.

My 14.04LTS setup with proprietary Nvidia drivers works fine on this PC :-S

Can anybody help me find what is wrong?

Comment: I've been asking the same questions on forums.  What I've seen on mine (upgraded from 14.04) was that the process of building the 361 nVidia driver into the kernel was failing at depmod.  Did you notice any error messages when trying to install the proprietary drivers?

Comment: I have to drop from 32 to 16GB ram until Nvidia rolls out an updated driver.   Ugh...nvidia!

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. It seems that after installing Nvidia driver on 16.04 problems occur with SATA DVD rom devices on certain mainboards. After I disconnected my SATA DVD writer and did reinstall with USB DVD reader and installed Nvidia 361 driver everything worked! I changed the SATA port on mainboard after install for built-in SATA DVD writer (swapped it with one of my ZFS SATA disks) and now all is hunky dory!